# Chrome ASP.NET session vanishes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I'm using ASP .NET with VB, no other frameworks or Ajax, only ASP Charts.

web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" cookieName="ASPMPT"/>
```

> Logging in is done via a form and SQL.

The session times out after 10-20 seconds, and I see that Session_End from `global.asax` is called, then a new session is created. This happens only in Chrome, the other browsers work well.

I also tried using `StateServer` but no success.
ASP .NET State service is already started.

Answer (score 0):

Set mode="StateServer" in web.config and do the following steps on your server :

1. Start
2. Control panel
3. Administrative tool
4. Services (you can also run services.msc to get there)
5. Find ASP.NET State Service
6. Right-click
7. Start

Comment: <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="20"  stateNetworkTimeout="30" />

Comment: just an idea : verify that your cookies are enabled in Chrome

Comment: Another idea: I had a similar situation when we had a very large tree view on the page. View state was very big and everything was crashing because of this.

Comment: The cookies are enabled, but Session_End gets called very soon on Chrome, especially when I do a postback. On the other browsers, the session works fine.

Comment: try pressing F12 in Chrome to see if there are any errors in the console